# -webkit-transform (rotateX) causes z-index to be ignored, affecting a button in separate div

Tags: javascript, css, less

***SOLVED:
After re-reading the w3 spec for transforms, I realised the footer was being considered part of the 3d context due to DOM structure and was being affected by rotated elements. I simply put  .cardsContainer  inside of another element  .cards3dContainer  and the footer is now not considered part of the 3d context.***

***-webkit-perspective:1000px;  seems to state that the 3d context begins at that point in the DOM.***

---

Having a major problem with a container that is being rotated using css3 transforms and over-writing part of a buttons hit area in another div.

The transform visually works and the container is leaning back (using rotateX). However, the button in the footer, despite being of a higher z-index and naturally stacked to be above the container, is having its hit area ignored where the rotated container and the button visually overlap.  The button still 'appears' to be on top of the rotated container, but acts like it is under it.

I should mention im using Less for the css (and all the Less code does work).

I've looked through lots of similar questions and the various solutions didn't work for me. Amongst those that didn't work (vendor prefixes omitted):
translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
transform-style: flat;

Here is the short version of the code:

```
html:
    <div class="screen snap" style="display: block;">
        <div class="container">**<!-- has perspective set to 1000 -->**
            <div class="cardsContainer"> **<!-- is rotated on x using transform -->**
                <div class="card" style="left: 130px; display: block;">
                    <div class="cardBack"></div>
                    <div class="cardFront" style="opacity: 0;">
                        <div class="cardContent">A piece of fruit.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                        **<!-- at certain screen sizes, when the container and footer overlap, top half of this buttons hit area is inactive-->**
                <button class="checkButton">Start</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Here are the full length files, look forward to any advice / tips:**

.html file:

```
<div class="screen snap" style="display: block;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cardsContainer">
            <div class="card" style="left: 130px; display: block;">
                <div class="cardBack"></div>
                <div class="cardFront" style="opacity: 0;">
                    <div class="cardContent">A piece of fruit.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card" style="left: 420px; display: block;">
                <div class="cardBack"></div>
                <div class="cardFront" style="opacity: 0;">
                    <div class="cardContent">Paint</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card" style="left: 420px; display: none;">
                <div class="cardBack"></div>
                <div class="cardFront">
                    <div class="cardContent">Nail</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card" style="left: 420px; display: none;">
                <div class="cardBack"></div>
                <div class="cardFront">
                    <div class="cardContent">Apple</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card" style="left: 420px; display: none;">
                <div class="cardBack"></div>
                <div class="cardFront">
                    <div class="cardContent">House</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <footer>
            <button class="checkButton">Start</button>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

.less file:

```
.screen.snap .container{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-color: #efe8b6;
    -webkit-perspective:1000px;

    .cardsContainer{
        position:absolute;
        width:800px;
        height:350px;
        top:100px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: lighten(#efe8b6, 10%);
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg);

        .card {
            position: absolute;
            width:250px;
            height:350px;
            border-radius: 10px;

            .cardFront{
                background-image: url('images/snap_card_front.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                width:250px;
                height:350px;
                position: absolute;


                .cardContent{
                    width:200px;
                    height:300px;
                    font-size: 37px;
                }
            }

            .cardBack{
                background-image: url('images/snap_card_back.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                width:250px;
                height:350px;
                position: absolute;
            }
        }
    }
}

footer{
    z-index:999;
    background-color: #f00;
    position: relative;

    .button{
        position:absolute;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier for people to tackle your question if you can isolate the problem to a smaller chunk of code.

Comment: thanks, just edited it to include focused short version of the html.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem.  You can actually post it as an answer and accept it; that way people will know your problem's been solved.

Comment: thank you, I would have done as you suggested, but as this is a brand new account and my reputation is low I couldn't answer my own question for a few hours the website said. Ill sort it now though.

Comment: ive added the answer but now I cant accept my answer for another day... the joy of having a brand new account and forced website delays ;)

Answer (score 2):

After re-reading the w3 spec for transforms, I realised what the problem was.

-webkit-perspective:1000px; seems to state that the 3d context begins at that point in the DOM. I was applying the perspective style to the container which both the footer and the cardsContainer were part of. The footer was then being considered part of the 3d context due to DOM structure and was being affected by rotated elements.

I simply put .cardsContainer inside of another element .cards3dContainer and the footer is now not considered part of the 3d context because it is now not inside the dom structure which has perspective style set.

The new structure is now this:

```
.screen.snap .container{
    .cards3dContainer{
        -webkit-perspective:1000px;

        .cardsContainer{
                }
     }

     .footer{
     }
}
```

- Apologies to anyone who may have been working on an answer at the moment.

Comment: website forced a delay on accepting this answer as its a brand new account... ill sort out in at least 24 hours.